# Creating a React (typescript) web project with an ASP.NET Core Web API all-in-one-project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a project in Visual Studio Enterprise which has React + ASP.NET Core Web API.

I can deploy it and it works great.

The beauty of this project/solution what that I can do UI + API development using the single IDE.

Now recently I updated the React sub-folder of this project so that I can take advantage of Typescript. I did this by re-creating the React app itself externally using VS Code.

Now I use VS Code for UI development and Visual Studio Enterprise for API development.

This complicated everything. Now I am finding it difficult to debug/test everything locally.

Perhaps there's a better/ideal way to go about this. But this setup I have now is certainly not it.

- How can I locally run/debug the API + React app?

Note that I am leaning towards separating into 2 projects:

- UI (react app)
- API (web api)